# Add class to element with dynamically added data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Ok, so I have a HTML file, that looks something like this:

```
while($stuff = $junk->fetch()){ ?>
    <div class="top-div" data-place-id="<?php echo $place['id']; ?>"></div>
    <div>
        <article>
            <div>
                //some stuff
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="expand" data-place-id="<?php echo $place['id']; ?>"></span>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
} ?>
```

As you can see, for each result from a database, a structure like this is being output. Naturally, there are going to be at least a few of these each time.
I wish to make it so, that each time the `span` is clicked, a class is added to the `<div data-place-id="">` where the data-place-id is the same as the clicked elements.

I tried doing it this way:

```
expandOverlay = function(){
    $(".expand").each(function(){
        $(".top-div").addClass('is-expanded');
    })
})
```

But, this just adds the class to every single element with this class.
Then I tried this:

```
expandOverlay = function(){
    $(".expand").each('click', function(){
        var dataAttr = $(this).data();
        if($(".place-overlay").data() == dataAttr){
             $(this).addClass("is-expanded);
        }
    })
});
```

But that didn't work either.

So, how do I get the .data() from my clicked element and how do I find other elements with the same data attribute, so I can assign it a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
   $('.expand').click(function(){

  dataid = $(this).data('place-id');
   $('div[data-place-id="'+dataid+'"]').addClass('is-expanded');
   })
```

- First grab the data attribute of clicked item
- Mave a div selection where data-place-id is same as span's data-place id ny concatenating the attribute selector.

Comment: I don't know why I always try to make things so complicated for myself. This is so much simpler and cleaner than anything I tried :)

Comment: Good to hear that it helped you to simplify your work @byr1al:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.expand').click(function() {
    $('div[data-place-id="' + $(this).data('place-id') + '"]').addClass('is-expanded');
});
```

Comment: A chunk of code with no explanation is not a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cristian has it right, but it may not need to be that complex. How about this?

```
$('span.expand').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div[data-place-id]').addClass('is-expanded');
});
```

Doesn't much matter what the `data-place-id` value is, does it?

Comment: ooh just beat me to it. Possibly the '.top-div' for the closest selector.

Comment: Yep, either way would do.

Answer (score 1):

this works?

```
$('span.expand').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.top-div').addClass('is-expanded');
});
```